# How to get value in single array extracted from nested array only through map function

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to get value in single array not in nested array without any additional operation outside map function.

```
const List = []
List.push(
    {
        name: 'John',
        id: 383,
        Value: [
            {
                "Age": "10"
            },
            {
                "Age": "20"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        id: 545,
        Value: [
            {
                "Age": "30"
            },
            {
                "Age": "40"
            }
        ],
    }
)

const ageList = List.map((list, index) => {

    let age = [];
    list.Value.map(item => {
        age.push(item.Age)
    })
    return age
})
console.log(ageList)
```

Orignal Output : [ [ '10', '20' ], [ '30', '40' ] ]
**Expected Output : [10,20,30,40]**

Comment: Does array.flat consider outside the map?

Comment: I have clearly mention that it should only happen through in map function only

Comment: but these are both poor uses of `map()`. Use the appropriate methods for the problem. `const ageList = List.flatMap(({ Value }) => Value.map(({ Age }) => Age));`

Comment: this is an ideal usecase of flatmap

Comment: @user1702396 I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work well
The age array needs to be declared outside

```
var age=[]
const ageList = List.map((list, index) => {

    
    list.Value.map(item => {
        age.push(item.Age)
    })
    return;
})
console.log(age)
```

Comment: Don't use `map()` unless you are going to use the returned arrays. These should be `forEach` calls.

Comment: But he says he need to use map function

Comment: i think @pilchard solution is work fine and proper method to execute

Answer (score 0):

as I understand your code in your age array you are exactly getting the desired result. instead of printing and assigning agelist you can just use the map methods
as below

const List = []

```
List.push(
{
    name: 'John',
    id: 383,
    Value: [
        {
            "Age": "10"
        },
        {
            "Age": "20"
        }
    ],
},
{
    name: 'Mark',
    id: 545,
    Value: [
        {
            "Age": "30"
        },
        {
            "Age": "40"
        }
    ],
}
```

)

List.map((list, index) => {

```
let age = [];
list.Value.map(item => {
    age.push(item.Age)
    
})
```

})
console.log(age)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way :**

```js
const List = [{
  name: 'John',
  id: 383,
  Value: [
    {
      "Age": "10"
    },
    {
      "Age": "20"
    }]
},{
  name: 'Mark',
  id: 545,
  Value: [
    {
      "Age": "30"
    },
    {
      "Age": "40"
    }
  ],
}];

const age = [];

List.forEach((list, index) => {
  list.Value.forEach(item => {
    age.push(item.Age);  
  })
});

console.log(age);
```